# how to delete a record in rails API and vue Js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vuejs2, rails-api

i am trying to delete an ActiveRecord form rails API and Vue js using the axios library. I can fetch and add records without any issues .The issue I have is deleting a record

Here is my code

rails API
.....

```
# DELETE v1/customers/1
 def destroy
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @customer.destroy
end
```

Vue Js
........

```
<tr v-for="customer in customers" :key="customer.id">
  <td>{{customer.first_name}}</td>
   <td>{{customer.last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{customer.email}}</td>
     <td>{{customer.id}}</td>
     <td><button @click="removecustomer(customer.id)"
     type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Delete</button></td>
```

```
 export default {
  name: 'customers',
    data (){
        return{
            customers:[]
        }
    },
    created (){
        this.getallcustomers()
    },
     methods: {
       getallcustomers () {
             let uri = 'http://localhost:3000/v1/customers';
            this.axios.get(uri).then((response) => {
               this.customers = response.data;
               console.log(this.customers);

            });
       },
        removecustomer(id){
             let uri = `http://localhost:3000/v1/customers/${customer.id}`;
             this.axios.delete(uri).then((res) => {
               this.customers = this.customers.filter(customer => customer.id !== id);



            });
        }
    }

}
```

So my `removecustomer` methods produce an error `customer is not defined"`

I need help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only passing only customer id as paramteter (`id`) to the `removecustomer` function and not the entire `customer` object, thus, you are getting an undefined error.

Replace:

```
let uri = `http://localhost:3000/v1/customers/${customer.id}`
```

With:

```
let uri = `http://localhost:3000/v1/customers/` + id
```

Comment: I changed customer.id to id . But code did not work , I am using rails as the backend So I have just customer.id in the object customer. Don’t have just an id key

Comment: As per your question, you have error in JS `removecustomer` function : `customer undefined` and replacing the code that I suggested should solve this issue. If you are facing any other difficulty, you can update the question with appropriate error that you are getting so that I can understand better and will be help you.

Comment: Thanks, I had to configure cors to allow delete request.

Comment: @pkimtani is there a way to delete based on something other than `id`, e.g. based on `name` ? (asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56825149/curl-command-to-delete-from-rails-api-based-on-where-predicate)