# Curl command to DELETE from rails API based on where predicate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, ruby-on-rails-5

I can see from [here](https://medium.com/@ConnorFinnegan/how-to-use-curl-to-test-a-rails-api-55fd2c43c999) how to delete a table record by id

i.e. this deletes the user record with id = 1

```
curl -X DELETE "http://localhost:3000/users/1"
```

But what if I wanted to delete records based on something else, e.g. all users with `name: "John"`, how would that be done via a curl command?

Update: I thought `curl -X DELETE -d "name=John" "http://localhost:3000/users"` may work, but it doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that scenario, the API would change a bit. The route for the default `DELETE` API on Rails requires an ID to be passed as input compulsorily. The request format is `some_api/:id`. However, for your use case, you would need a different API which does not compulsorily require an ID as input. It could be a multipurpose API which deletes by name, id etc. For example:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def custom_destroy
  @users = User.filtered(filter_params)
  @users.destroy_all
  <render your response>
end

def filter_params
  params.permit(:id, :name, <Any other parameters required>)
end

# app/models/user.rb
scope :filtered, -> (options={}) {
  query = all
  query = query.where(name: options[:name]) if options[:name].present?
  query = query.where(id: options[:id]) if options[:id].present?
  query
}
```

The route of this could be described as:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    delete :custom_destroy
  end
end
```

This would result in the route: `localhost:3000/users/custom_destroy` which can be called with the `DELETE` action. i.e.

```
curl -X DELETE "http://localhost:3000/users/custom_destroy?name=John"
```

Comment: to add to this answer, what would the curl request look like ? ```curl -X DELETE "http://localhost:3000/name=John"```

Comment: @Anuj I have tried `curl -X DELETE "http://localhost:3000/users/custom_destroy&name=John"` and `curl -X DELETE -d "name=John" "http://localhost:3000/users/custom_destroy"`. Both return `{"status":404,"error":"Not Found","exception":"#\u003cActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=custom_destroy\u0026name=John\u003e"`

Comment: Also, does `def filter_params`  etc go in the 'private' part of the controller?

Comment: I have been fiddling, but still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: `filter_params` would go into the private section.
I'll just try out a couple of things on my local machine and get back? It's strange that you're getting a 404. Did you restart the server after adding the route?

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal Yes I restarted the server between attempts. Thanks for looking into it, it's probably something I'm doing wrong, I am trying different things, but no luck yet

Comment: I've mistyped the route as `resources :user` instead of `resources :users`. Is that correct on your machine?

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal I hadn't fixed that. I fixed it, and tried `curl -X DELETE -d "name=John" "http://localhost:3000/users/custom_destroy"`. It worked (sort of) - it deleted the entire table - it didn't limit the destroy action to users with `name: John`

Comment: Alright, I've tried this on my local machine, and it seems to be reaching the controller method. I have a feeling that the incorrect route might be a problem

Comment: Oh, yes. That must've been because the parameters did not reach the model at all. Check using `binding.pry` or `byebug` if your controller action is receiving the `name` parameter. Also, let's move this to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195767/discussion-between-user5783745-and-anuj-khandelwal).